# How to know last Sunday of month

Tags: date, vmware

i try writing script on ESXI and i need add "if last Sunday of month". I try

```
date -d @$(( $(date -d $(date -d @$(( $(date +%s) + 2678400 )) +%Y%m01) +%s) - 604800 )) +%d
```

It can not work, but it work on Debian.

On ESXI now output August

Comment: I expected that `date -d "$year-$month-01 +1 month -1 week Sunday"` would work, given that "*The explicit mention of a day of the week will forward the date (only if
necessary) to reach that day of the week in the future*", but it seems to be ignored when preceded by an absolute date.

Comment: @TobySpeight ah, indeed. I was mislead by the "if last sunday", thanks.

Comment: @TobySpeight determine whether a date is the last Sunday of a month. I weel try your version

Comment: Related: [How to use bash to get the last day of each month for the current year without using if else or switch or while loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12381501/1672723)

Comment: On ESXi 7.0.0  the `date` command identifies itself as `BusyBox v1.29.3 (2019-08-06 16:32:32 PDT) multi-call binary`. It understands `--date` but not date arithmetic. There is no `cal` or `ncal`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the question is

> Given a particular date, can I determine whether it is the last Sunday in the month?

and not the more general question

> Given a particular month, on what day is its last Sunday?

Given that, we can divide the problem in two:

- Is the date a Sunday?
- Is it the last week of the month?

For the first part, the test is easy enough:

```sh
date -d "$date" +%a  # outputs "Sun" for a Sunday
```

We can test that:

```sh
test $(date -d "$date" +%a) = Sun  # success if $date is a Sunday
```

Now, to test whether it's the last week of the month, we can add one week to the date, and see if that gives us one of the first 7 days of the next month:

```sh
test $(date -d "$date + 1week" +%e) -le 7
```

Since the weekday of `$date + 1week` is the same as that of `$date`, we can generate both parts of the test in one go, and use a Bash regular expression test:

```sh
if [[ $(date -d "$date + 1week" +%d%a) =~ 0[1-7]Sun ]]
then
    echo "$date is the last Sunday of the month!"
fi
```

Tested:

```
$ ./330571.sh 2016-12-01
$ ./330571.sh 2016-12-04
$ ./330571.sh 2016-12-25
2016-12-25 is the last Sunday of the month!
$ ./330571.sh 2017-01-28
$ ./330571.sh 2017-01-29
2017-01-29 is the last Sunday of the month!
```

Comment: Ok, but ESXI not understand 1week. "$date + 1week" may replace on date -d @$(( $(date +%s) + 604800))

Comment: I was assuming the GNU implementation of `date` - if you can't install that, then I guess you're stuck with the one you're given.  Seems like you've found a suitable workaround, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `cal` and `awk`:

```
$ cal | awk '/^ *[0-9]/ { d=$1 } END { print d }'
25
```

### Explanation

`cal` prints the current month with Sunday as the first column (by default):

```
$ cal
    December 2016
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
             1  2  3
 4  5  6  7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17
18 19 20 21 22 23 24
25 26 27 28 29 30 31
```

The `awk` command matches for lines starting with zero or more spaces, followed by a digit, and stores the first field into variable `d`. At the end, `d` will be the last Sunday of the current month.

Comment: In ESXI not command cal or ncal.

Answer (score 0):

I found this article when trying to get the last thursday, but it would work for any other day too. Here is my solution (compatible with Bash):

```
thisThursInMonth=`date +%m`
nextThursInMonth=`date -d 'next thursday' +%m`
if [ $nextThursInMonth -ne $thisThursInMonth ]
...etc...
```

Essentially, it checks if the day in next week occurs in the same month. Should work for Dec/Jan transitions, since I used `-ne` instead of `-ge` or `-gt`.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Can you confirm that it works with the `date` tool available on ESXi?

Answer (score -2):

```
if ( (( $(date +%d -d "$now") > `expr $(date +%d -d "$(date +%Y -d "$now")/$(date +%m -d "$now")/1 month day ago") - 7` )) && (( $(date +%w -d "$now") == 6 )) );
  then echo "Today ($now) is BLACK SABBATH"
fi
```

Answer (score -2):

For the last Sunday of the month:

```
if [[ $(date -d "$date" +%a) = Sun && $(date -d "$date" +%m) != $(date -d "$date + 1week" +%m) ]]
```

For the first Sunday of the month:

```
if [[ $(date -d "$date" +%a) = Sun && $(date -d "$date" +%m) != $(date -d "$date - 1week" +%m) ]]
```

Comment: Please explain this. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: That was copy paste issue. It's fixed now.

Comment: As noted in the question this is for ESXi, which does not have relative date maths such as `+1 week`.

Comment: Please explain this. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; edit your answer to make it clearer and more complete.