# How to set up a cronjob that runs on the last sunday of each month?

Tags: linux, centos, rhel

I am trying to set up a cronjob to run on the last sunday of each month. This is what I have accomplished.

Right now, it is running every sunday at 10 PM.

```
0 22 * * 0 /usr/basys_bin/clean_cups_cache.sh
```

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/330571/how-to-know-last-sunday-of-month

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cron entry for last Saturday](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/550835/cron-entry-for-last-saturday)

Comment: yes, and thank you

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/689834/6030 = Use Dillon Crontab version.

Answer (score 1):

Either in the top of your script, or as a separate script, you can put a safe-guard to ensure that it will only run during the last week of the month.

For example, create this as something like `/usr/local/bin/lastweekofmonth`

```
#!/bin/bash
# Exit 0 ("OK") iff we are in the last seven days of a month
#
today=$(date +%d)                             # Day number today
nextweek=$(date --date 'now + 7 days' +%d)    # Day number next week

[[ ${today#0} -gt ${nextweek#0} ]]            # Implicit exit "OK" if today > next week
```

Remember to make it executable (`chmod +x /usr/local/bin/lastweekofmonth`)

Then you can use it in your `crontab` entry

```
0 22 * * 0 /usr/local/bin/lastweekofmonth && /usr/basys_bin/clean_cups_cache.sh
```